# jgitflow maven plugin: Merge release to remote-dev and remote-master branch?

Tags: git, maven, bamboo, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I have started using the jgitflow-maven-plugin and I am trying to automate releases with bamboo.
Basically the plugin is working. We are using a development-branch and the master-branch.
Running jgitflow:release-start and jgitflow:release-finish updates the version numbers correctly for the releases. 
What I am missing is that the changes

1. incrementing SNAPSHOT version on development-branch
2. incrementing major-release number on master-branch
3. creating a tag on the master-branch

are not pushed and merged to the remote repository.

The merges only seem to be done in the local repositories on bamboo.
I would have expected the plugin to handle the push as well.

Below my pom-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <flowInitContext>
      <masterBranchName>master</masterBranchName>
      <developBranchName>development</developBranchName>
      <releaseBranchPrefix>release-</releaseBranchPrefix>
    </flowInitContext>
    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
    <alwaysUpdateOrigin>true</alwaysUpdateOrigin>
    <defaultOriginUrl>ssh://git@my-remote-repo.com/app.git</defaultOriginUrl>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could try to add `<pushReleases>true</pushReleases>` to the `configuration` at least that is what [the documentation](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow/wiki/goals/release-finish#!pushreleases) says or just add a shell script task to your Bamboo build plan which does a `git push ...`

Comment: Thanks <pushReleases>true</pushReleases> solved the issue. I would have assumed that this option would just have the created release-branch pushed to the remote repository. But with this option set all changes are pushed to the remote repository.